# Can non-alphanumeric characters be used as selectors?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

The following code compiles and runs fine (note the `sel_registerName("+")`):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@interface Integer : NSObject
{
    NSInteger   intValue;
}

@property (assign) NSInteger intValue;

@end

@implementation Integer

@synthesize intValue;

- (id) plus:(Integer*)anInteger
{
    Integer* outInt = [Integer new];
    [outInt setIntValue: intValue + [anInteger intValue]];
    return outInt;
}

@end


int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    id pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    SEL plusSel = sel_registerName("+");
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([Integer class], @selector(plus:));
    class_addMethod([Integer class], plusSel, method_getImplementation(m), method_getTypeEncoding(m));

    Integer* i4 = [Integer new];
    Integer* i20 = [Integer new];
    [i4 setIntValue: 4];
    [i20 setIntValue: 20];

    Integer* res = objc_msgSend(i4, plusSel, i20);

    NSLog(@"%d + %d = %d", [i4 intValue], [i20 intValue], [res intValue]);
    //  >> 4 + 20 = 24

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Other than "yuck", are there reasons to be cautious about doing this?

Comment: Reflection can be used for all sorts of fun stuff. Doesn't make it ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The API to the ObjC runtime is unlikely to change, but the validity of calling sel_registerName("+") might. I've monkeyed around in the ObjC runtime a lot, and haven't run into any problems even after many updates.  That being said, I wouldn't base a multimillion dollar business on this continuing to work forever.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Objective-C runtime library doesn't perform any checks on the content of the string you are trying to register and it's unlikely that the development team change that behavior. If it is a non-empty C string, if you always use `objc_msgSend` to send messages for that selector and if you don't try to do something like `[i4 +:i20]` (which is going to cause a compiling error), there is no reason to be afraid.

Registered Objective-C selectors are actually C strings stored internally by the runtime system. The runtime system keeps a table of pointers to C strings, the so-called SEL set. When you call `sel_registerName` the ObjC runtime system calls `strcmp` for your string and for each C string stored in the SEL set. If any of the C strings in the SEL set is equal to the one you want to register, the function returns the address of the corresponding C string in the set. Otherwise, the system duplicates your string (with `strdup`), stores the resulting pointer in the SEL set and returns it. This new pointer becomes a new unique selector.